# Extract first three characters of a string with words with bash, f.ex. with sed

Tags: bash, sed

From the string "Release Enterprise Production" I need to extract the first three characters of each word and put together the string "RelEntPro". I can put this in one line, but it's rather long:

```
export APP_NAME=""; 
for i in Release Enterprise Production; do 
   APP_NAME="$APP_NAME${i:0:3}"; 
done; 
echo $APP_NAME
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this with sed? or awk?

Comment: Try [`sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\{3\}\)[^ \t]*[ \t]*/\1/g' <<< "$APP_NAME"`](https://ideone.com/PlgFHG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some tips to shorten your loop:

- `export` is unnecessary.
- `+=` is a shortcut for concatenation.
- `${i:0:3}` can be shortened to `${i::3}`.
- Quotes aren't necessary on the right hand side of an assignment.

(It's best to avoid all uppercase variable names as they're reserved by the shell, so I changed `APP_NAME` to `appName`.)

```
appName=; for n in Release Enterprise Production; do appName+=${n::3}; done
```

Another way to do it is by using `grep -o` to match three characters at the beginning of each word and only print out the matching bits.

```
str="Release Enterprise Production"
egrep -o '\<...' <<< "$str" | tr -d '\n'
```

Or you can use Awk and loop over each field.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s",substr($i,0,3); print ""}' <<< "$str"
```

Answer (score 2):

You use cut to take chars:

```
echo 'Release Enterprise Production' | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -c-3 | echo $(cat) | sed 's/ //g'
```

outputs:

```
RelEntPro
```